# Calling a setting from a .config file in C# returns the type of value instead of the value

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-services, app-config

I have 2 C# Projects.
Project A has access to Project B's .config file (via the internal app settings). I have proof of functionality as B can access specific values of Project A's config file.

When querying one specific value in Project A's config file Project B instead returns the type that it is. It's very strange.

I have the same chunk of code, yet Proj B returns the type, and Proj A returns the value.

It's worth noting that the value itself is a List of objects which are serialized. The items are serialized and deserialized at will without any difficulty, this is done at various parts. The same code to do so is used in both projects, and in Project B during deserailization the project uses a MessageBox.Show or EventLog.Write() to output what the current value is before deserailization, and in Project A it shows the value ...

```
</xml version="1.0"?><MyValues xmlns:xsi="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ...
```

However in Project B it simple states:

```
System.Collection.Generic.List'MyObjectType
```

Or something along those lines, despite the fact the code is identical. Before deserialization so its definitely something with the config file, or maybe how a Windows Service interprets it.

There isn't really any code I could quote which could help as the code is identical since it is the circumstances which alter the code.

I am hoping someone could shed some light as it is a Windows Service and Windows Form sharing the .config file.

**EDIT:**

```
string temp = Settings.Default.MySettings;
```

Printing out temp in Project A =

```
...</xml version="1.0"?><MyValues xmlns:xsi="ht...
```

Printing out temp in project B =

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectA.MyClass]
```

*(temp = some XML values)
However the same code in another project gives out some code which is an object type. Despite in plain text there is no object type explicitly listed?*

*(May not reply till morning)*

Comment: Your lack of precision has gotten in the way of you finding the answer on your own: Project B was not returning the type. It was returning a string representation of the type. That's not the same thing.

Comment: But why was it? Why can't it just return the plain text? Project B has access to the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be specific on where the problem is because you don't post any actual code, but I can tell you that somewhere you are relying on an implicit conversion to a `string` type. This is what you see when you call `.ToString()` on a List. It could be that it works in other places because you pass a single object instead of a List, and your type overrides `.ToString()` and so the implicit string conversion results in something meaningful. The main thing is that one case you use a single object, and in the other your sending a collection of objects.

Comment: You're still missing any relevant code... but my answer stands: Project A works because you're only using single objects. Project B has a collection.

Comment: Project A is using a collection of objects, which Project B has access too though? I just don't understand why Project B can't return the plain text of the config file.